# How to set default download directory in selenium Safari Capabilities?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch

I have being looking around for documentation related to setting Safari capabilities. The browser does not download the file to the given path.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'safari',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        options: {
          dataDir : 'my/path/here'
        }
      },
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I therefore tried  ```'safari:safariOptions': { dataDir : 'my/path/here' }  ```

Comment: ```chrome: { prefs: { 'profile.password_manager_enabled': false, download: { default_directory:'my/path/here }}}}} ```

Works in Chrome